# count number of rows between rows where value is 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
client, visit page 2
1,0
2,0
3,1
4,0
5,1
6,0
7,0
8,1
```

now I want to know how many clients have been since the last client visited page 2. So the outcome would be:

```
client 3, 3; client 5, 2; client 8,3
```

eventually I only need to numbers of occurrences of the gaps so here I would have as an ultimate answer:

```
gap,# occurrences
1,0    
2,1
3,2
4,0
```

Is this possible in mysql and best would be without a for loop?

The data is to large to load it completely in python/php. 
One way would be to use python/php and select all rows where 'visit page 2' is 1 and then do a for loop with a select query with count(rows) between succes n-1 and succes n. But this takes to much time.

Comment: Look into user variables

Comment: Approximately what proportion of the records have "visited page 2"? And the order of this data is the client number (an auto-inc?)?

Comment: You have 1 and 4 with 0 occurrences. What includes/limits those rows?

Comment: @w3d about 2.5% are visits, and the order is by client number

Comment: @JRD, there are no limits, just to maximum gap in the data but I think 10000 would be a safe maximum.

Comment: Since those are just manufactured rows, you could generate those in the client, at display time. If you really needed to have the data returned from the query, join to a table with a least 10,000 rows and has a row for range( 1 .. 10,000).

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept answers if appropriate. Even feedback such as "this is junk and makes no sense". We use that  feedback, and cheers us on to help the next guy, regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Creates the effect of a **row_number** with the `@rn` variable, and maintains the prior row number where vp2=1 occurred in variable `@lastWas`.

The cross-join facilitates not having to do set @rn:= etc stuff at the top. And that is the sole purpose of it.

Note the derived table named `inr`. All derived tables require an alias name even if not used explicitly by name. One can run the innards of the derived table separately. This is used at the beginning of development for a sanity check, then several of the columns there can be ignored in the query on the outside that wraps it. Certainly as seen here. See **inr-only** at bottom of answer for a view of just that derived table.

### Schema

```
create table x
(   id int auto_increment primary key, 
    client int not null,
    vp2 int not null
);

insert x(client,vp2) values 
(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),
(5,1),(6,0),(7,0),(8,1);
```

### Query

```
select client,rn-lastWas as gap from
(   select id,
    client,
    vp2,
    @lastWas as lastWas,
    greatest(@rn:=@rn+1,@lastWas:=if(vp2=1,@rn,@lastWas)) as junk, -- forces recalc immediacy inside greatest() function, caring not at all of results
    @rn as rn
    from x
    cross join (select @rn:=0 as r,@lastWas:=0 as l) as blahJunk
    order by id
) inr
where vp2=1
```

### Results

```
+--------+------+
| client | gap  |
+--------+------+
|      3 |    3 |
|      5 |    2 |
|      8 |    3 |
+--------+------+
```

[Advanced Mysql User Variable Techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/)

---

### inr-only:

This is a view of just the `inr` derived table, to help visualize the above.

```
+----+--------+-----+---------+------+------+
| id | client | vp2 | lastWas | junk | rn   |
+----+--------+-----+---------+------+------+
|  1 |      1 |   0 | 0       | 1    |    1 |
|  2 |      2 |   0 | 0       | 2    |    2 |
|  3 |      3 |   1 | 0       | 3    |    3 |
|  4 |      4 |   0 | 3       | 4    |    4 |
|  5 |      5 |   1 | 3       | 5    |    5 |
|  6 |      6 |   0 | 5       | 6    |    6 |
|  7 |      7 |   0 | 5       | 7    |    7 |
|  8 |      8 |   1 | 5       | 8    |    8 |
+----+--------+-----+---------+------+------+
```

---

**brownie points section below**

### More schema

```
create table bon
(   -- bunch of numbers
    i int not null
);
insert bon(i) values (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

### Brownie points query

```
select bon.i as gap,ifnull(qry.rowCount,0) as occurrences
from bon
left join
(   select gap,count(*) as rowCount from
    (   select client,rn-lastWas as gap from
        (   select id,
            client,
            vp2,
            @lastWas as lastWas,
            greatest(@rn:=@rn+1,@lastWas:=if(vp2=1,@rn,@lastWas)) as junk, -- forces recalc
            @rn as rn
            from x
            cross join (select @rn:=0 as r,@lastWas:=0 as l) as blahJunk
            order by id
        ) inr -- derived table alias
        where vp2=1
    ) xxx -- every derived table requires an alias
    group by gap
) qry -- derived table alias
on qry.gap=bon.i
```

### results

```
+-----+-------------+
| gap | occurrences |
+-----+-------------+
|   1 |           0 |
|   2 |           1 |
|   3 |           2 |
|   4 |           0 |
+-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, keep a total of the current gap and reset on each visit.

```
select v, count(*) from(
    select client,
           case when visit = 0 then @v := @v + 1
                else @v := @v + 1 end v,
           case when visit = 1 then @v := 0 end gap
    from table join (select @v := 0) v
    order by client
) q
where gap is not null
group by v
;
```